# Windows Forms Application C# Style

Tags: c#, styles

I am developing a Windows Form Application in Visual Studio 2008 (C#)
And I want to add Style to the items.

I have been investigating a few ideas about it but I have not found an example about how to do it.  Is it really possible?

My app looks like:

> [image: application screenshot]

But I really want to add more style in buttons, textboxs and other items I have:

> [image: example styles]

My boss insists on using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Use WPF not Windows Forms...

Comment: You can use themes that come with winform, or use image as background...if not use WPF :)

Comment: In fact the controls I can see in your second picture are just simple to create with basic `GDI+`. However there are too many controls to **customize** here. You have to do it yourself, no one can help. If you don't know how to customize a control, just find more example, or simple ask another question about specific control with some attemp of your own, someone can help. I think you should **persuade** your boss to use a third party **UI library**, it saves much time for you and of course the controls are much skinnier.

Comment: There comes a time when you need to make a hard decision: Either keep doing windows-95 like applications in winforms, or use a better UI Framework.

Comment: Tell your boss from my part: `While we lose time troubleshooting winforms' incapabilities, people are doing stuff like` [**this**](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/) `in WPF`.

Comment: Could you please tell us what you ended up doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this without purchasing anything else, you could create your own custom button and text box controls, either from scratch or as controls derived from the existing windows forms controls and then overriding OnPaint etc. Take a look at what's been done here:

http://dotnetrix.co.uk/button.htm

You could also investigate third party options.

Or, use WPF if that's a possibility as others have said. I'd push for WPF! If there's an existing WinForms Code base you can always host WPF Elements in WinForms. See:

[Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Presentation Foundation Control in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

IF you wana to use Winforms than you have to buy this one for example:

http://devcomponents.com/
You have to bind the new assemblies in your application that is not a lot of work!

But better way do that with WPF
http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html