# Use style from wpf for a windows form app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, forms, xaml

I'd like to add a style to the items I have in some forms, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18596434/2246344) the link of my preview question.

This app is developed in Visual C#, a WPF app, I have an `.xaml` file and 65 windows forms.

I have don't have a problem with any of the styles in the `.xaml` file, but in the `Form.cs` file I can't add any styles.

I'd like to have the same button style in both files (`.xaml` & `.cs`).

How can I do it? Should I add some libraries? Do I have to add more lines of code to `Form.cs`? Or should I do everything using the `.xaml` files?

I've been looking for something like this but I have not found anything.

I apologies if I'm asking silly questions.

Comment: *"somewhat silly"? Only **SOMEWHAT?***

Comment: Are you trying to mix WinForms and WPF?

Comment: You already asked that in your last question. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @BoltClock♦ I'm a newbie here... I'm asking help... **_I'd rather ask and look like an idiot ... to be one_**     **Tim** How could I do it?       **Daniel** Yes, I did and I still don't understand :(     **MyCodeSucks** Could You teach me how "move" myself here... AS I said _I'm a newbie_

Comment: Being a newbie doesn't excuse you from abusing formatting. Please keep your questions coherent and free from gratuitous bolds and italics and cries for help, otherwise people aren't going to take them seriously and you'll be even less likely to get answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

winforms doesn't support Styles, nor Theming. It's a really old technology that has not been improved since 2007. it's not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications.

Your options are:

- redo everything in pure WPF.
- Change all winforms UI elements to `ElementHost`s containing WPF content. This is even worse than redoing everything.
- Buy a third party such as DevExpress.
- Contact a FreeLancer developer (such as myself) who is willing to re-do all your winforms into beautiful WPF UIs (for profit)

Comment: Hey, @HighCore, thank you so much.... I'll say it to my boss... I don't know what he'll say... But thank you... I'll be here for a long time! (it's a threat ;) ) **THANK YOU SO MUCH**