# C# and define common theme

Tags: c#, css, xaml, colors, themes

I have one windows form application in visual studio 2013 , C# language, I want to define something like CSS file , which is defined for web apps , but for my application.
So as a result I want to have one app that   when I run application , all the forms and buttons will have same colors and are got their styles from the common file.
Is it possible? if so, how can I do that?
 thanks in advance

Comment: You make an WPF application, don't you?

Comment: No , it is not WPF application.. that is winform application

Comment: how can I make a WPF application? can you tell me or send me a link which describe this task step by step? thanks

Comment: Here is the example:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb655895(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Also here is a similar question for winforms. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596434/windows-forms-application-c-sharp-style

Answer (score 0):

**WinForm:** 
For winForm application you should create your own custom controls, from scratch or derived from existing one. Probably someone has already done it, like DevExpress.
If you are not planning to purchase anything, I suggest to use WPF.

**WPF:**
In order to make a theme you have to make a `ResourceDictionary` with a list of  [Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx) for a different controls.

So, create a new [ResourceDictionary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx), implement a lot of styles for particular controls. 
For example, style for `RepeatButton`

```
<Style x:Key="TestStyle" d:IsControlPart="True" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then in your application add a reference to the `ResourceDictionary`.

```
<Application x:Class="ThemesSample.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ExpressionDark.xaml"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

You can find some examples [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes&referringTitle=Home)